# Apex batch getting an error out

Tags: batch, scheduled-apex

I have this Apex batch having issues with call. I am new in this apex-world. Can someone help me out. My code is here.

```
global class Samplelotinactive implements Database.Batchable<Sample_Lot_vod__c>
{
    Public String query;
    Public String email;

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        query = 'SELECT ID,Active_vod__c FROM Sample_Lot_vod__c where Expiration_Date_vod__c=NEXT_N_DAYS:60 and Active_vod__c=true'; //need to define query
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Sample_Lot_vod__c> m)
    {
        List<Sample_Lot_vod__c> m1 = [SELECT ID,Active_vod__c FROM Sample_Lot_vod__c where Expiration_Date_vod__c=NEXT_N_DAYS:60 and Active_vod__c=true];
        for (Sample_Lot_vod__c s: m){
            s.Active_vod__c=false;
        }
        update m;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        mail.setToAddresses(new String[]{email});
        mail.setReplyTo('saikatkumarneogy@gmail.com');
        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Batch Processing Completed');
        mail.setPlainTextBody('Sample lots inactivated');
        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your current issue? What do you mean by having issues with call.

Comment: Hi Lance, sorry if I am not clear about it. I get this type error.  Error: Compile Error: Samplelotinactive: Class must implement the global interface method: Iterable<SOBJECT:Sample_Lot_vod__c> start(Database.BatchableContext) from Database.Batchable<SOBJECT:Sample_Lot_vod__c>, Samplelotinactive: Class must implement the global interface method: void finish(Database.BatchableContext) from Database.Batchable<SOBJECT:Sample_Lot_vod__c> at line 1 column 14

Comment: I have to inactivate the flag value for all those records that are returned by the SOQL query. Please let me know the way out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Database.Batchable nominally supports parameterised types (using the `<>` notation) but it appears that when returning Database.QueryLocator rather Iterable from the `start` method you have to stick to `<SObject>`.

(Note that returning Database.QueryLocator rather than Iterable from the `start` method usually gives better performance and allows the batchable to process up to 50 million records rather than hitting a governor limit at 50,000 records.)

This will compile and execute:

```
global class Abcd implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {   ...
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Sample_Lot_vod__c> m)
    {
        ...
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: @saikat Cool. Click the tick to accept the answer so people know that the question no longer needs answering.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you need is just a finish class - even if it is empty:

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
}
```

To use batch apex, you can follow this guide: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm

It should direct you to the right place

Comment: Thanks Lance. I tried it. Updated my code here. Still seeing this error.                                            Error: Compile Error: Samplelotinactive: Class must implement the global interface method: Iterable<SOBJECT:Sample_Lot_vod__c> start(Database.BatchableContext) from Database.Batchable<SOBJECT:Sample_Lot_vod__c> at line 1 column 14